# Wordpress character encoding with apostrophes issues

Tags: php, html, wordpress, utf-8

I am getting strange character encoding on my Wordpress website when I use apostrophes. Every single page and post where I use apostrophes outputs things like the following:

- isnât
- ÃÂ
- Readyâ
- â

I have contacted my hosting who were less than useful but told me that “the database seems to be correctly set to utf8mb4 encoding”

I have checked wp-config and it also says utf8, view source on the page says utf8 also.

I’ve tried commenting out:

```
//define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
//define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Adding “-“ in to match view source output

```
//define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf-8"');
```

I've changed typography settings to use Ariel with no joy. In the page editor, there are no indications of the weird characters, everything looks fine. It's just the output on the page?

Not sure where else to turn now :-(

Comment: Does the problem go away when you do View → Encoding → UTF-8 in your browser?

Comment: No its still there when forcing it to use UTF-8, also ran `document.characterSet` in console in dev tools, said it was UTF-8 also. However, the weird characters are all still there

Comment: Do those characters exist in the database itself…?

Comment: In the json output its showing it as `didn&#8217;t` . Done an UpDraft plugin back up of the SQL and it shows it as `didn\'t`

Comment: There's no dodgy characters in the SQL database, all looks fine ie: apostrophes showing ok

Comment: Creating a new page or post - I don't get any of the character encoding issues. It just seems to be with existing pages and posts. Also, updating/editing existing posts don't have an effect.

Answer (score -2):

i think that's because of your function file, can you try with default theme

and this way you can fix previous errors

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'â€œ', '“');
```